# How to return HTML from an external protocol handler in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, protocol-handler

I have an *external* protocol handler set in `about:config` as `network.protocol-handler.app.myproto=/myapp.exe`.

I want `myapp.exe` to return an HTML to Firefox, which should be exhibited just like a webpage is.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some research and experiments, I'm forced to conclude this isn't possible.

Comment: That's a shame. I still need this feature badly.